# Filtered result on search are unpredictable results

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, search

I am implementing a search functionality where input box which will search over a list of users with following fields.

id: a unique id
name: user’s name
items: list of items ordered by user
address: address of the user
pincode: user address pin code

Search needs to be implemented on all of the fields data.

Data: http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ba8efb23100007200c2750c

Problem: The search results are absurd such as searching "Jo" would also display results with "Ja" and "12" would also give result of "aa" and "32"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQbaY.png)

SearchBox Component:

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react'
import '../stylesheets/searchbar.css';
import Card from './Card';

export default function SearchBar({ placeholder, data }) {
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState('');
  const [filteredResult, setFilteredResult] = useState([]);
  const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
  
  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    if (value.length === 0) {
      setFilteredResult([])
      setSearching(false);
    }
    if (value?.length > 0) {
      searchItems(value);
      setSearching(true);
    }
  }

  const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
    setSearchInput(searchValue);
    if (searchInput.length !== 0) {
      const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
        return Object.values(item).join(' ').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase());
      });
      setFilteredResult(filteredData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='search'>
      <div className='searchInput'>
        <input type="text" placeholder={placeholder} data={data} onChange={handleSearch} />
      </div>
      {
        filteredResult?.length > 0 ? (
          <div className='searchResult'>
            {filteredResult.map(({ id, name, address }, i) => (
              <Card key={id} id={id} name={name} address={address} searchInput={searchInput} filteredResult={filteredResult} />
            ))}
          </div>
          ) : (
          <div>
            {searching ? (
              <div className='searchResult'>No user found</div>
            ) : (
                null
            )}
          </div>         
        )
      }
    </div>  
  )
}
```

Expected:

- The search results should display the items in a predictable fashion such as search "Beno" should return 1 user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First check the full content of the apparently absurd items

After this line

```
 setFilteredResult(filteredData);
```

add

```
 console.log(`searchInput: '${searchInput}'`)
 console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData, null, 2))
```

That will enable you to check if the case that appears unexpectedly for a `searchInput` of "Ja",  happens to have "Ja" somewhere inside one of the properties, for example in the address or pin code.

#### Restrict the search to just a few properties

If you don't want some properties to be included in the search, include only the properties that you want.

For example, you might want to search on unique user id.

#### What did the `searchInput` log, immediately above that output, say?

I ask because  the example you give definitely does not fit `123`. Therefore `searchInput` must have been not 123, but something else. Perhaps it was just 12 or even 1? What was printed out?

[image]

#### Ahh! The problem is that searchInput has not yet been updated

Change the `searchInput` inside the loop to `searchValue`.

i.e. change this:

```
  const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
    return Object.values(item).join(' ').toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase());
  });
```

to this:

```
  const filteredData = data.filter((item) => {
    return Object.values(item).join(' ').toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  });
```

#### Explanation

According to this:

```
https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useState
```

> ###### Pitfall
>
> Calling the set function does not change the current state in the already executing code:

```
function handleClick() {
  setName('Robin');
  console.log(name); // Still "Taylor"! 
}
```

> It only affects what useState will return starting
> from the next render.

Comment: Consoled the above lines and while searching "123" results in these items too
```
{
    "id": "abc-34-122",
    "name": "Jason Jordan",
    "items": [
      "Mobile"
    ],
    "address": "Riverbed Apartment",
    "pincode": "4xx032"
  }
```

Comment: My `searchValue` log says searchValue: '123' and this user was present in the filtered array of items.

Comment: Searching `345` gives result
`[
  {
    "id": "223-a1-234",
    "name": "Soloman Marshall",
    "items": [
      "bottle"
    ],
    "address": "Riverbed Apartment",
    "pincode": "4xx032"
  },
  {
    "id": "abc-34-122",
    "name": "Jason Jordan",
    "items": [
      "Mobile"
    ],
    "address": "Riverbed Apartment",
    "pincode": "4xx032"
  }
]`

Comment: Sorry, change the console log to `searchInput`, not `searchValue`, since `searchInput` is what you are testing for presence in the loop.

Comment: `searchInput: 'joh'
SearchBar.jsx:30 [
  {
    "id": "123-s2-546",
    "name": "John Jacobs",
    "items": [
      "bucket",
      "bottle"
    ],
    "address": "1st Cross, 9th Main, abc Apartment",
    "pincode": "5xx012"
  },
  {
    "id": "323-s2-112",
    "name": "John Michael",
    "items": [
      "Refrigerator"
    ],
    "address": "1st Cross, 9th Main, abc Apartement",
    "pincode": "5xx012"
  }
]`
searchInput takes one less character than what I type.
I typed `John` but `searchInput` had `Joh`. How may I fix this?